# Work-around for hotkey and searchBox function

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a gridview for Menu and that Menu has over more or less 30 items in it so I implemented a seach box for that Menu. Now my problem is that I assigned hotkeys for button click events and when I try to type those hotkeys in the search box, it won't register instead it would do the click event.

Is there a work-around for that situation where when I type in the search box the hotkeys would register and the click events wouldn't perform and when I am not typing on the searchBox, the hotkeys would perform as it should.

This is the sample of my hotkey event.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            switch (keyData)
            {
              case Keys.A:
                  if (buttonThatDoSomething.Enabled == true)
                  {
                      buttonThatDoSomething.PerformClick();
                  }
                  return true; 
              default:
                  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a work-around for the situation I am in, it works for me
I put a condition that would check the search box focus and if so then the keyData would return its default input.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case Keys.A:
                    if (buttonThatDoSomething.Enabled == true && searchBox.Focused == true)
                    {
                        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
                    }
                    else if (buttonThatDoSomething.Enabled == true && searchBox.Focused == false)
                    {
                        buttonThatDoSomething.PerformClick();
                    }
                    return true;
                default:
                    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
            }
        }
```